# problem running dcvviewer from Nice DCV on Fedora 31

Tags: fedora

I need to run dcvviewer from Nice DCV (https://www.nice-dcv.com) on Fedora 31 but I get this error message here:

```
/usr/libexec/dcvviewer/dcvviewer: symbol lookup error: /lib64/libgtk-3.so.0: undefined symbol: g_mount_operation_set_is_tcrypt_hidden_volume
```

and I can check that `g_mount_operation_set_is_tcrypt_hidden_volume` is not available in `/lib64/libgtk-3.so.0`:

```
# nm -D /lib64/libgtk-3.so.0 | grep g_mount_operation_set_is_tcrypt_hidden_volume
                 U g_mount_operation_set_is_tcrypt_hidden_volume
```

but it is available in `/lib64/libgio-2.0.so`:

```
# nm -D /lib64/libgio-2.0.so | grep g_mount_operation_set_is_tcrypt_hidden_volume
000000000008af60 T g_mount_operation_set_is_tcrypt_hidden_volume
```

Both libraries are link in dcvviewer binary:

```
# ldd /usr/libexec/dcvviewer/dcvviewer
    [...]
    libgio-2.0.so.0 => /lib64/libgio-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f63411db000)
    [...]
    libgtk-3.so.0 => /lib64/libgtk-3.so.0 (0x00007f633f18b000)
    [...]
```

It used to work on Fedora 30.

Is there a way to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the version of glib provided by `dcvviewer` is 2.56. The new version of GTK 3 requires a newer version of glib and that is why you see this failure. In order to work around this you can either:

- Delete `/usr/lib64/dcviewer/libglib*`, `libgio`, `libgthread`, `libgmodule`, `libgobject` from that directory. In this way `dcvviewer` will use the system copy which is newer instead of using the copy provided by `dcvviewer`.
- Wait for the next version of `dcvviewer` which will fix this issue.

Comment: Perfect! It is working. Thank you.